# How can I change CSS styles on Javascript Elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like the Movie Title and the Movie Year to show up with the style that i've set in my CSS file. Currently, the javascript created elements are showing up just plain black text.

The styles for these classes should be showing up as larger white text with a google font.

What am I missing here?

Please see code for HTML, CSS, and vanilla JS.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.0/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-Avb2QiuDEEvB4bZJYdft2mNjVShBftLdPG8FJ0V7irTLQ8Uo0qcPxh4Plq7G5tGm0rU+1SPhVotteLpBERwTkw=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/fxno-w" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Movie App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <h1>FIND YOUR <span class="gradient-text">FAVORITE</span> MOVIE.</h1>
      </header>

      <input type="text" id="movie-search-box" onkeyup="findMovies()" />

      <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>

      <div class="result-grid" id="result-grid">
        <!-- <div class="movie-card" id="movie-card">
          <img class="movie-cover" />
          <h3 class="movie-title">Aquaman</h3>
          <h4 class="movie-year">(1994)</h4>
        </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   background: #333333; 
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;                                
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

/* Main header section */

h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    font-family: 'fx logo'
}

.movie-title {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

.movie-year {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1 rem;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

/* Changes "Favorite" text to a gradient */

.gradient-text {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #d41044, #f89f03);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/* Input box section */

input {
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #222222;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.562);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=text]{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.616);
}

.fa-magnifying-glass {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.searchBtn {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #333333;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.searchBtn:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.116);
    cursor: pointer; 
}

/* Movie Results Grid Section */

.result-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));

}

.movie-card {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.movie-cover {
    width: 200px;
}


/* js related classes */
/* .hide-result-grid {
    display: none;
} */
```

JS:

```
const movieSearchBox = document.getElementById("movie-search-box");

function findMovies() {
  const searchTerm = movieSearchBox.value;
  const resultsGrid = document.getElementById("result-grid");

  if (searchTerm.length > 2) {
    fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchTerm}*&apikey=dd3f37db`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((movieResults) => {
        movieResults.Search.forEach((movie) => {
          const movieCard = document.createElement("div");
          movieCard.classList.add("movie-card");
          resultsGrid.append(movieCard);

          const movieTitle = document.createElement("h3");
          movieTitle.classList.add("movie-title");
          movieCard.append(movie.Title);

          const movieYear = document.createElement("h4");
          movieYear.classList.add("movie-year");
          movieCard.append(` (${movie.Year})`);

          console.log(movie.Title);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `movieCard.append(movie.Title);` appends text to the movieCard, completely ignoring the `movieTitle` element you created - similar mistake with `movieYear` element, also completely ignored - in other words, `movieTitle.append(movie.Title); movieCard.append(movieTitle);` instead of `movieCard.append(movie.Title);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over here, you are in complete error. I have made corrections:

```js
const movieCard = document.createElement("div");
movieCard.classList.add("movie-card");
resultsGrid.append(movieCard);

const movieTitle = document.createElement("h3");
movieTitle.classList.add("movie-title");
movieTitle.textContent = movie.Title;
movieCard.append(movieTitle);

const movieYear = document.createElement("h4");
movieYear.classList.add("movie-year");
movieYear.textContent = movie.Year;
movieCard.append(movieYear);

console.log(movie.Title);
```

The assumption is that `movie.Title` and `movie.Year` are well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will get errors so I have made some modifications to prevent those.

```
    const movieCard = document.createElement("div");
    movieCard.classList.add("movie-card");
    resultsGrid.append(movieCard);
    const createElement = (tag, text, className) => {
    const element = document.createElement(tag);
    element.classList.add(className);
    element.textContent = text;
    return element;
    };
    movieCard.append(
    createElement("h3", movie.Title, "movie-title"),
    createElement("h4", `(${movie.Year})`, "movie-year")
);
console.log(movie.Title);
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for this. This code looks shorter and a lot cleaner. I am new to coding so forgive me if this doesn't make complete sense. What code would I enter after the return element; 'enter code here' section?

Comment: That's comment which is missed out there.